# AlwaysOn SQL VNet Migration from Azure V1 (ASM) to V2 (ARM)

Tags: sql-server, azure, alwayson

Hoping someone can help!

Currently in the middle of planning a migration from Azure Service Manager to Azure Resource Manager.

Not able to find any documentation and thought I would reach out.

When using the method of `Move-AzureVirtualNetwork` to migrate Virtual Machines from ASM to ARM. If a SQL Alwayson cluster is the only Availability Set in that Virtual Network.

When it is migrated, is there any impact to the cluster?

If so, is the fix to completely re-configure and re-deploy the cluster?

Thanks,
Lachie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all VMs in the cloud service are in the same availability set, then you are good to go. Migration is transparent and without downtime. If there's any incompatibility, the preparation phase will tell you.

> - You have more than one availability set in a single cloud service.
> - You have one or more availability sets and VMs that are not in an availability set in a single cloud service.